# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `check_public'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer, diaspora

I am working on an issue on diaspora* related to email notifications:

#### Private post: show a link (no text) in the email notification

#### Public post: show a summary and a link in the email notification

Here is my Pull Request to diaspora*: https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/pull/4508

Link to my Github Repo: https://github.com/railsgirls-generator-app/diaspora/tree/4266-remove-content-from-email-notifications

[This](https://github.com/railsgirls-generator-app/diaspora/blob/4266-remove-content-from-email-notifications/app/views/notifier/comment_on_post.markerb) line gives an error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `check_public' for #<#<Class:0xd1e5638>:0xb5081bf4>):
1: <% ispublic = check_public(@notification.post) %>
2: <% if ispublic == true %>
3: <%= comment_message(@notification.comment, :process_newlines => true) %>
4: 
  app/views/notifier/comment_on_post.markerb:1:in `_app_views_notifier_comment_on_post_markerb__51526760__628881328'
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

i am just guessing, as i would have to know the codebase better to really understand the issue.

what i can see from a glance:

1. you are calling `check_public` in a mailer template
2. `check_public` is defined in `app/helpers/notifier_helper.rb`
3. an error is raised because the method is not exposed for rendering

so i guess that including `NotifierHelper` in `CommentOnPost` would fix the problem.

Comment: Did u mean in this file diaspora/app/mailers/notification_mailers/comment_on_post.rb??

Comment: The same problem exists. I think I am adding wrong arguments for the check_public method in the views.